# Problem with String Splitting in Java (MAC ADRESSES)

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have this server which registers observations of MAC Addresses. When a client wants to see observations of a given MAC Address, he can make that request using either a complete MAC or a fragmented MAC. Valid requests can be the initial or end of a MAC Address consisted of 8bit multiples, examples follow:

- ***FF:*** - First 8bits of a MAC Address
- ***FF:AA:*** - First 16bits of a MAC Address
- ***:FF*** - Last 8bits of a MAC Address
- ***:AA:FF*** - Last 16bits of a MAC Address
- ***:AA:BB:CC:DD:FF*** - End of a MAC Address without the first 8 bits.
- ***AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF*** - Full MAC Address

These examples are **not** permitted:

- ***FF*** - Must end **or** start with " : " to let the server know it is an initial fragment
- ***FF:AA*** - Must end **or** start with " : " to let the server know it is an initial fragment
- ***:FF:*** - No middle fragments allowed
- ***OO:JJ*** - No non-hexadecimal characters allowed.

Here is the code I have:

```
    private static boolean isMAC(String mac) {
        String[] fragMACs = mac.split(":");

        if (fragMACs.length > 0 && fragMACs.length <= 6) {
            for (String s : fragMACs) {
                if (s.length() != 2) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    try {
                        Long.parseLong(s, 16);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

At the moment my function does not work for the following cases:

- Any fragment that starts with " : ", the split function will mess it up.
- It does not contain the verifications for making sure it is not an in-the-middle mac fragment. (AA, AA:AA, :AA:)

The last verification is easy, a simple if statement like this:

```
if ((mac.charAt(0) == ':' && mac.charAt(fragMACs.length - 1) == ':') 
    || (mac.charAt(0) != ':' && mac.charAt(fragMACs.length - 1) != ':')) { 
    return false; 
}
```

should do the trick.

My problem is with that split clause. Is there any suggestions on how to fix this efficiently?

Comment: You're having a problem with pattern matching - to me, this screams REGEX.

Comment: Yes but in only fails when the input string starts with ' : ', how can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with a regular expression relying heavily on *positive and negative lookaheads* for doing much of the validation. The regex is:

```
^(?=(:|.*:$|.{17}$))(?=.{3,17}$)(?!.{4}$):?[0-9A-F]{2}(:[0-9A-F]{2})*:?$
```

The principal portion is:

```
:?[0-9A-F]{2}(:[0-9A-F]{2})*:?
```

1. `:?` optional colon
2. `[0-9A-F]{2}` followed by 2 characters in the set `[0-9A-F]`
3. `(:[0-9A-F]{2})*` followed by 0 or more occurrences of a colon followed by 2 characters in the set `[0-9A-F]`
4. `:?` optionally followed by a colon

The real enforcement takes place at the beginning of the matching before any characters are scanned using lookaheads:

1. `(:|.*:$|.{17}$))` The string must either begin with a colon, end with a colon or be exactly 17 characters long
2. `(?=.{3,17}$)` The entire string must be from 3 to 17 characters long (this eliminates, for example, `FF`)
3. `(?!.{4}$)` But the string cannot be 4 characters long (this eliminates `:FF:`)

The code:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] tests = {
            "FF:",
            "FF:AA:",
            ":FF",
            ":AA:FF",
            ":AA:BB:CC:DD:FF",
            "AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF",
            "FF",
            "FF:AA",
            ":FF:",
            ":OO:JJ",
            ":AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF",
        };
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?=(:|.*:$|.{17}$))(?=.{3,17}$)(?!.{4}$):?[0-9A-F]{2}(:[0-9A-F]{2})*:?$");
        for (String test : tests) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
            System.out.println(test + " " + (matcher.matches() ? "match" : "no match"));
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
FF: match
FF:AA: match
:FF match
:AA:FF match
:AA:BB:CC:DD:FF match
AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF match
FF no match
FF:AA no match
:FF: no match
:OO:JJ no match
:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF no match
```

Comment: Even though I personally avoid using such long regex expressions, it is very compact and really well explained. You should possibly change `[A-F]` to `[0-9A-F]` because the OP mentions MAC addresses.

Comment: @Eritrean You're absolutely correct and I have updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: This was so useful, thank you so much. I think I'm gonna study a bit more about regex, this saves me tons of lines of coding...

Answer (score 3):

Spliting using the word boundary `\b` can make this task easier since it doesn't consumes any input text letting you keep the delimeter `:`. For example the following statement outputs:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF".split("\\b")));
// [AA, :, BB, :, CC, :, DD, :, EE, :, FF]
```

And instead of parsing the hex strings in a try-catch, I would go with a simple regex

```
[0-9A-F]{2}
```

to get any combination of the digits from `0 to 9` and letters `A to F` with the exact length of `2`

Adding the above together, your code could looklike something like below:

```
private static boolean isMac(String mac) {        
    String[] parts = mac.split("\\b");
    //Full MAC Address
    if (parts.length == 11){
        return Pattern.compile(":").splitAsStream(mac)
                      .allMatch(s -> s.matches("[0-9A-F]{2}"));
    }
    //input shouldn't start and end with ':'
    else if(mac.startsWith(":") && mac.endsWith(":")){
        return false;
    }
    //input should start or end with ':'
    else if( !(parts[0].equals(":") || parts[parts.length-1].equals(":")) ){
        return false;
    }
    //rest
    return Pattern.compile(":").splitAsStream(mac)
                      .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                      .allMatch(s -> s.matches("[0-9A-F]{2}"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :D